# Set limit and check memory usage of subprocess.Popen in Python

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, subprocess, memory-limit

I am developing online judge using Django on Debian. All user scripts I call with subprocess.Popen. To check script time usage I use time module and to limit timeout I'm giving parameter timeout to communicate on process object and handling subprocess.TimeoutExpired exception. Is it possible to do something similar to check memory usage of process and limit it?

That is a code sample how I do it now:

```
    try:
        execution = subprocess.Popen(execute_line.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
        execution.stdin.write(bytes(test.input_data, 'UTF-8'))
        execution.stdin.flush()
        start_time = time.time()
        test_output, test_error_string = execution.communicate(timeout=time_limit)
        end_time = time.time()
        finish_time = end_time - start_time
        test_output = test_output.decode('utf-8')
        test_error_string = test_error_string.decode('utf-8')    
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        end_time = time.time()
        finish_time = end_time - start_time
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight-forward one-liner easy way to check for memory consumption.

Solutions:

1. You can use `psutil` (*pip install psutil*), for example:

```py
def get_process_memory():
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    return process.memory_info().rss


def track(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        mem_before = get_process_memory() / 1024 ** 2
        start = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        elapsed_time = elapsed_since(start)
        mem_after = get_process_memory() / 1024 ** 2

        metrics = {
            'callable': func.__name__,
            'memory_before': mem_before,
            'memory_after': mem_after,
            'memory_used': mem_after - mem_before,
            'exec_time': elapsed_time
        }
        print(f"{json.dumps(metrics, indent=4)}")
        return result

    return wrapper
```

2. Use similar approaches including `resource` Python library (only works on Unix systems)

```py
    # Memory consumption with psutil (MB)
    import os, psutil; print(psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2)

    # Memory consumption with resource (MB) - Only works on Unix
    import resource; print(resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss / 1024)
```

3. Use `tracemalloc` - a bit more complex IMHO
4. Use an external process/software to monitor metrics of your processes